# Change background color on a selected Item in WPF with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, background

Basically, I want have a listBox and I want to change the color of the background and foreground of the item that I currently have selected.

I tried this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFAFA212"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But it didn't do anything at all. I tried searching for it but nothing i tried seemed to work, can anyone help please? This is an App.xaml in a c# project btw.

Comment: @KlausGütter it does somewhat, but the background is not changing, just the foreground, but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more complicated than you might imagine because of how wpf uses control templates to build controls.

The templates for a listbox and listboxitem is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

There are a number of ways you could accomplish this but I think the most informative would be to re template.

Here's something to take a look at. Put this in a parent control ( like the window or grid) resources:

```
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
   TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
            Padding="2"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="Yellow" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="Yellow" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup  x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="#FFAFA212" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Note that only one visual group can apply at a time and the last one wins.

There are subtleties to this.

See the line

```
 <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
```

Remove that and see what happens